# How to decode &amp; etc using XQuery/SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xpath, xquery, xquery-sql

Using Microsoft SQL Server...

```
declare @x xml
set @x = '<Example>&lt;You &amp; Me&gt;</Example>'
select cast(@x.query('/Example/text()') as nvarchar(50))
```

The result is "&lt;You &amp; Me&gt;" rather than "<You & Me>".

How can I have SQL read the XML in such as way that '&lt;', '&amp;' and '&gt;' are decoded?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`value()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030) instead of `query()`.

```
declare @x xml
set @x = '<Example>&lt;You &amp; Me&gt;</Example>'
select @x.value('(/Example)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)')
```

[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/1823)